# How to retrieve password policy error from Active Directory using Windows LDAP SDK

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am using Windows LDAP SDK to manage users of Active Directory.

When I modify user's password which doesn't meet a password policy requirement, then the returned error code is 53 which is "Unwilling to perform".

I wanted to retrieve the actual error message generated by Active Directory. For this I have used ldap_get_option() with option LDAP_OPT_SERVER_ERROR. The error returned with call is "err=0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A129B, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0". This error message also doesn't give information about the failure with password policy.

Is there any other API call by which I can get the actual error message from active directory?

Thanks.

Comment: Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the extended request and respone  operations for change password, not just alter the attribute directly.